# Python testing - on-the-fly interactive mock building?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've come up with an idea of on-the-fly interactive mock building. It means that I'd register an object:

```
session = requests.Session()
mock_building.start(session)
```

and then when I invoke:

```
session.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

It would make a request to stackoverflow as usual and save Response (somewhere).

Then I'd make something like:

```
mock_building.save(session, "stackoverflow_session.dat")  # pickling?
```

And later (in next execution) I'd do:

```
session = mock_building.load("stackoverflow_session.dat")
```

And this time:

```
session.get("http://stackoverflow.com")  # overloaded __getattr__?
```

Would give me exactly the same Response but without request to stackoverflow.

Is this thing possible? Please note I do not want to limit myself to requests module, I'd be great for developing/testing in general case (for example when a program raises an Exception on the 300th line and getting there takes a lot of time). Or would it be not?

Comment: What do `start`, `save`, `load` and `get` do exactly? It's hard to tell from your examples.

Comment: "start" is starting to watch "session" object, save saves already cached object to file, and load loads it. get() is just an arbitrary method that returns some value (which is time consuming). In this example it's an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [requests-cache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache)

You can caching all requests to e.g. sqlite db

```
import requests
import requests_cache

requests_cache.install_cache()

requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```